# Advice: How can I smoothly translate my artistic logo into a text logo? (Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, critique

I'm currently designing my club's logo and I'm having trouble finding a simple way to translate to text-only for brochures and such. I was hoping I could receive some constructive advice. This is my first go at Illustrator, so I've stumbled quite a bit already.

Should I use the same two fonts I've already used? More than one line, or just flat out on one?

Thanks in advance,

Luna

PS - Any advice on transparent fade-out in the trees will be happily accepted, that was very tough to do in Illustrator.

[image: Bellevue CSIT]

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking for feedback/advice on how to simplify your logo?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to presume that when you mean "text-only brochure" you mean "8.5 x 11 monochrome laserjet." I won't get into a critique of the logo itself.

With some leeway for size and production considerations, a logo is basically meant to be unalterable: it must be used like a badge without amendment.

However, the designer (you) is tasked with coming up with a few alternates for specific purposes, and typically, this means a full one, an approved reduced-content version for specific use-cases (like those corporate sponsor logo banners), and then 1-color, 2-color, 4-color, and RGB versions of those.

You will also want to have a version that does not require a 100% black flood fill on the whole piece or force all your collateral to have a black banner to accommodate the logo mark.

So the "easy" way for the image posted is to invert all colors, then desaturate all colors, then adjust the contrast/levels to produce a black and white version. Obviously this would be done differently and more appropriately with the original illustrator file. For AI, just "make all the black, white; then make all the colors black"

For a 1-color version, you probably want to eliminate the neon-glow effect, and reconsider the gradient. For printed items, you can have quality issues with fine dot patterns: sometimes "dot gain" floods the gaps and causes a splotchy appearance or screws up the contrast. Also, tight gradients may not print well on a t-shirt.

Note that a true greyscale (not rgb or cmyk) is really a brightness map, and is suitable for 1-color printing whether that color is black or some other ink.

Below is the result of (in Photoshop): ctrl+I,ctrl+U (desaturate fully),ctrl+L (levels adjust the darks to black and the lights to white).

[image]

Comment: As far as a critique goes, I would simply say that the most important thing a designer can do, no matter the project, is "eliminate two things." I think maybe Coco Chanel said something like this.